# how to return several response instead of only once to spider in scrapy selenium middleware

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, return, arguments

I am using the python scrapy framework to crawl car info on below page:

```
https://youjia.baidu.com/view/carDatabase?title=%E7%8E%B0%E4%BB%A3&key=code&val=174&sa=pc_growth_1
```

but this page is using something like infinite scroll technique to automatically loads json when you scroll down on the page. Every page 25 results, for different car brand page, the qty is different, so sometimes it needs to separate the results into 1~3 pages by scrolling down.

So I was wondering that maybe I can integrate some codes into the selenium middleware as below:

```
from scrapy import signals
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.http.response.html import HtmlResponse
import random
import time


class SeleniumDownloadMiddleware(object):
def __init__(self):
    # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def process_request(self,request,spider):
    self.driver.get(request.url)
    time.sleep(1)
    source = self.driver.page_source
    response = HtmlResponse(url=self.driver.current_url,body=source,request=request,encoding='utf-8')


    return response

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 2
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        source = self.driver.page_source
        response = HtmlResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=source, request=request, encoding='utf-8')
        return response

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
```

but the problem is this middleware only return response once, so the spider.py only parse once.
How can I modify this snippet to realize 1~3 times return?

Comment: anybody can help me? or am i not making problem clear enough?

Comment: You need to return `Response`, try using `process_response` method.

Comment: @SerhiiShynkarenko hello can you be more specific? I mean when I scrolled down, page 2 , page 3, loads, and then return response again.  very returned reponse will be used by the spider.

Comment: the loop is like this: 1st page1 spider initiate parse, forward a request to engine >>> 2nd, engine forward request to downloader to get the response of page1, >>> 3rd, downloader return response to engine >>>4th, engine pass extracted data as items output to spider. >>> 5th, spider initiate page2 request.  So I need to launch more than once request in spider. right? The keypoint is to launch more than once request respectively to page1~3. How can I integrate several "initiator" into the spider code?

Comment: `process_request` doesn't return response, you need [`process_response`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_response). Take a look at [Scrapy architecture](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow) to understand why. Also dynamic load on scrolling means that there are additional requests executed by web page, investigate how that requests are built, maybe you will not need even Selenium. Also executing requests in middleware looks like a wrong place.

Comment: process_request does return response.  it returns none/request/response/raise Ignorerequest 4 results.  so I checked your answer later half. when scroll down a one page high maybe, additional request was built...  yes, maybe no need selenium, maybe json would be good. I am figuring how to loads it and extract it.